# readonly_fields + blank=False triggering a ValidationError

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model defined with ForeignKey relations to other two custom models.

```
class PersonGroupMembership(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey('group.Group', related_name="person_memberships", blank=False)
    person = models.ForeignKey('staff.Person', related_name="group_memberships", blank=False)
    # other properties
```

When I am adding an instance, it works fine as all fields are non read-only. But I have added a condition in my Admin class, to make those two ForeignKey read-only when editing an existing instance:

```
class PersonGroupMembershipAdmin(TranslationAdmin):
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return ()
        return 'group', 'person'
```

This is triggering a ValidationError when I am editing an existing instance, without stack trace at all. How can I get rid of it?

[image: validation error]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Plz add full trace ...

Comment: Hi, there is not any trace. It's just a validation warning, but it does not highlight any field. I guess because its field is read only. Look into my edit